# Security Exception - Trying to load MySite Blog

Tags: 2010, development, security, silverlight

When I try to run this async query it fails:

```
    private void SomeFunction()
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(GetBlogInfo);
        thread.Start();
    }

    private void GetBlogInfo()
    {
        this.clientContext = new ClientContext(this.strMySiteBlogUrl);
        this.oWeb = this.clientContext.Web;
        this.clientContext.Load(this.oWeb);

        this.oList = this.oWeb.Lists.GetByTitle("Posts");
        this.clientContext.Load(this.oList);
        CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
        query.ViewXml = "<View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='PublishedDate' Ascending='FALSE'></FieldRef>" +
            "</OrderBy></Query><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title'/><FieldRef Name='Body'/>" +
            "<FieldRef Name='PublishedDate'/></ViewFields><RowLimit>1</RowLimit></View>";
        this.oListInfo = this.oList.GetItems(query);
        this.clientContext.Load(this.oListInfo);
        this.clientContext.ExecuteQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);
    }
```

This is within a Silverlight Application, fyi.  I thought it was a threading issue, but it just says:

- Exception   {System.Security.SecurityException ---> System.Security.SecurityException: Security error.
  at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
  at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.<>c_*DisplayClassa.b*_9(Object sendState)
  at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c_*DisplayClass4.b*_1(Object sendState)
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)
  at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.OnGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)}    System.Exception {System.Security.SecurityException}

Any ideas?

Comment: does the user account running the script have permission to the site?

Comment: I'm wondering if this is because of MySites being on a separate web application... I'm looking into work arounds...

Comment: Yes, definitely, I'm actually on a dev set up, pulling my own user blog

Comment: What line is it erroring on exactly?

Comment: trying this now:
http://www.dev4side.com/community/blog/2010/8/15/security-error-using-sharepoint-2010-client-object-model-for-silverlight.aspx

Comment: The ExecuteQueryAsync line, I know the Uri is valid.

Comment: cool, let us know how it goes.

Comment: solved.
It was because MySites is hosted on a separate Web Application.  Configuring the ClientAccessPolicy.xml solved my problem. There is a sample on this page:

http://www.dev4side.com/community/blog/2010/8/15/security-error-using-sharepoint-2010-client-object-model-for-silverlight.aspx

And best practice guidelines for production here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645032(VS.95).aspx

Comment: Good job, post it as an answer below and mark it complete

Comment: I tried, I have to wait 7 more hours, but I will.

Comment: Seriously, I was stuck on this for half a day because the error says it's invalid cross thread access until you dig in deeper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configuring the ClientAccessPolicy.xml solved my problem.

There is a sample on this page:

http://www.dev4side.com/community/blog/2010/8/15/security-error-using-sharepoint-2010-client-object-model-for-silverlight.aspx

And best practice guidelines for production here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645032(VS.95).aspx